# Process get all from front-end or back-end?

Tags: java, spring, pagination

I have create a resource like this:

```
@GetMapping("/books")
public ResponseEntity<List<Book>> getAllbooks(BookCriteria criteria, Pageable pageable) {
    Page<Book> page = bookService.findByCriteria(criteria, pageable);
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
}
```

I want to export this content into a file. Should I call request one by one page for this request or process this one in back-end and get all like this:

```
@GetMapping("/books")
public ResponseEntity<List<Book>> getAllBooksWithoutPageable() {
    log.debug("REST request to get a page of books");
    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    int page = 0;
    int size = 20;
    Slice<Book> slice = bookService.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, size));
    books.addAll(slice.getContent());

    while (slice.hasNext()) {
        page += 1;
        slice = bookService.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, size));
        books.addAll(slice.getContent());
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(books);
}
```

Comment: If you want to export everything just don't paginate the results, no?

Comment: What's the point of paging, if you still collect everything in memory, before sending it to frontend? Looks like more work for no benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think that it will all fit in memory, you can do the "un-paging" in the backend.

If not, you do it in the client because the client can of course write the data to the file page-by-page and does not need to keep it all in memory.

Third option is to do it in the backend, using a stream if your database supports that. Then you can stream the content from the DB to the client without pages, and without ever having to store everything in memory. [Here is an SO Q+A for that scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58668900/streaming-data-over-http-with-java).